# Magento API - how to retrieve data without hurting server performance

Tags: magento

We are developing an app that pulls data from our customer's Magento system via their API.  We are concerned about slowing down their server(s) performance if, for example, they have lots of products, orders, customers, etc.

Is there a best way to throttle what we retrieve from our clients so that we don't impact their server's performance?